# decided by themselves/them/them themselves

Tags: personal-pronouns

Which of the following options is correct?

> There are more and more career women. Their value is decided by **them** / **themselves** / **them themselves**.

Answer (score 1):

Q. Which of the following options is correct?
There are more and more career women. Their value is decided by them / themselves / them themselves.

---

A. **None** Their value is decided by them / themselves / them themselves. **Needs to be re-written** as

*Their value **"being"** decided by them / themselves / them themselves.*

---

**The correct answer would then become**

***There are more and more career women, their value being decided by themselves.***

Although in a stand-a-lone context it makes little sense to me.

**Note**

> **They, them**; We use they and them to refer to specific groups of people, things and animals:

> **Example;** The kids are getting on my nerves. **They’re** making so much noise. Can you tell **them** to be quiet? I’m trying to work.

> **themselves**: pronoun: used when the subject of the verb is "they" or a group of people, and the object is the same group of people:
> **Reflexive pronouns** end in -self or -selves. They refer back to the subject forms of personal pronouns (underlined in the example below):We often use reflexive pronouns when the subject and the object of the verb refer to the same person or thing:

> **Example;** Parents often blame themselves for the way their children behave

---

Meaning of **"is"** in English; he/she/it form of be

**be verb** (DESCRIPTION); used to say something about a person, thing, or state, to show a permanent or temporary quality, state, job, etc.

---

ALL Ref CED [themselves](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns-reflexive-myself-themselves-etc)

**be verb** (DESCRIPTION) used to say something about a person, thing, or state, to show a permanent or temporary quality, state, job, etc.